# Should accepting an answer on meta give a reputation bonus?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta

Given that meta doesn't lend itself to every question having a single correct answer, it seems wrong that you can accept a particular answer.

I may be missing the mark, but you've got three classes of question here on meta:

- Tech support issues for SO/SF ("Where's my rep"/"How can I track my rep"/etc.)
- Feature/enhancement requests ("How about this new badge"/"Can we have comment notifications in the RSS feeds"/etc.)
- Opinion questions ("should easy questions be closed"/"How to deal with unwritten rules"/etc.)

Of those, I only see the tech support issues actually having an answer worth accepting, and seems that it could be exploitable if people started accepting answers, purely because they've of the same opinion for a feature request. Similarly, starting a bounty seems exploitable.

Comment: @ChrisF Since I don't see another announcement/post yet, can I interpret the [meta-tag:status-completed] as that accepting an answer won't yield any rep?  Or that you can no longer accept answers on meta?

Comment: Accepting an answer here will yield reputation (in line with votes). Other site child metas don't have separate reputation so voting and/or accepting doesn't change your rep.

Comment: @ChrisF Yea what does this mean status completed? I just tested and accepted an answer and it still gave me 2 rep. Your status completed here seems to indicate that my test should not of yielded 2 rep....

Comment: @ryan - I was reacting to a flag and my initial reading was that the issue was "solved". Perhaps I should mark it as [status-declined] then?

Comment: @ChrisF I think that would be the best solution here, as there hasn't been any changes to the behavior of accepting answers.

Answer (score 6):

Since meta rep only applies to meta anyway, I don't think it's a big deal. It only means that people respect your opinion on meta-discussions, not necessarily your technical acumen.

Accepting answers may still be important on subjective questions as well, because it **MAY** signify that the issue has been closed. In which case it makes sense to allow the moderators (or super moderators) select the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Though I initially suggested that the mechanism for accepting an answer be removed from Meta, as this site is intended to be more discussion-oriented, I have since [changed my mind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2860/what-changes-to-the-so-engine-are-necessary-for-meta), and I do think that, *when applicable* the ability of the topic starter to select a reply that has resolved their issue is important, and I think that the rep bonus is part of that.

Comment: Oh, and feel free to accept this answer :-D

Comment: I disagree - although meta has generally taken the form of Q&A, i think that's more a result of the format of the system itself - i'd rather encourage discussion here.

Answer (score 1):

Here on MSO voting and accepting give reputation using the same rules as on the main site. This is because:

1. MSO was the first meta site.
2. It covers network issues as well as SO issues.
3. It's special.

Other meta sites don't have separate reputation scores so while accepting an answer has the same meaning as on the main site it doesn't change your reputation.

Comment: +1 for "It's special". Take that other meta sites :P

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if a question **has** an answer, then accepting an answer is appropriate and should result in some reputation gain, at least to the answerer.  Since we allow questions (topics?) on meta that may not have an answer, however, perhaps we need to distinguish between questions and non-questions (discussions).  Questions would follow the normal scoring rules, where topics would not allow the ability to accept an answer (since there really is none).  The user would get the option of classifying the question at the time it was submitted, though it could be reclassified by people with significant reputation using voting rules.  Reputation gains for accepted answers would be rolled back if the question is classified as a discusssion.

Answer (score -1):

This has been [brought up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2860/what-changes-to-the-so-engine-are-necessary-for-meta) a bunch of times. Accepting an answer makes no sense on meta. We all get it already.

Comment: Can't say I could find any duplicates...

Comment: @rowland: No? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2860/what-changes-to-the-so-engine-are-necessary-for-meta

Comment: More of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Reputation doesn't even begin to make any sense on meta.