# What Stack Exchange website can I ask for website recommendations?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange community I can ask for website recommendations? Specifically, I am looking for a website that tells about the differences between two words that are often confused with each other. For example, race and ethnicity, affect and effect, mass and weight, weather and climate, college and university, etc. Basically, such a website would be like a catalog for "What is the difference between..." questions. I would be very grateful if someone pointed me to such a website.

Answer (score 4):

Such a question is off-topic on Software Recommendations: see
[Can I ask for recommended websites?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/23377) on their Meta.

[Some sites in the network allow for recommendations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75521/295232) (of products, tools, but also websites). Your best bet is to find a site about the topic your question is about, check if they allow recommendations or not, and if so, what requirements they have for recommendation questions.

Or try other Internet sites like Quora.

Answer (score 1):

In keeping with [Glorfindel's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/395995/280335) of finding an appropriate site on the SE network, then seeing as the subject matter is the use of the English language, maybe [the English Language Learners stack](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate, although I am not sure if they accept "suggest a web site" type questions. Here is the ELL.SE ["on-topic" page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Or maybe [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)? Although. I suspect that the former site may be more appropriate.

Comment: Searching for 'difference between' on ELU yielded many hits (13000?) on  questions/answers phrased pretty much as the OP stated.

Answer (score -3):

> Is there a Stack Exchange community I can ask for website recommendations? Specifically, I am looking for a website that tells about the differences between two words that are often confused with each other

Webservice recommendations are on-topic on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (see the corresponding [policy](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/44/903)).

Alternatively, one could ask a dataset request on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ (dataset for differences between two often confused words).

Comment: Not my downvote, but a [web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) is something else than a website.

Comment: @Glorfindel True. "Specifically, I am looking for a website that tells about the differences between two words that are often confused with each other" can be seen as a webservice.

Comment: Perhaps English Language Learners SE would be appropriate?

Comment: @JonCuster AFAIR off-topic there, but could ask on meta English Language Learners SE.

Comment: Actually looks like English Language & Usage would be better - many hits on 'what is the difference between X and Y' type of questions.

Comment: @JonCuster https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1107/3023 "resource requests are off topic here." but maybe ELL is itself the answer to OP's request ("website that tells about the differences between two words that are often confused with each other") :)

Comment: True, I was thinking ELU or ELL would be the answer. My bad.

Comment: @JonCuster FWIW IMHO they should make resource questions on-topic. Very useful for learners.

Comment: On [ell.se] and AFAIK [english.se], it's tradition to ask them on/move them to Meta: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/735/18673

Comment: Oh, and since [topic] Stack Exchange can be seen as a service providing the answer to your question about [topic], does that mean all SE web sites are web services?

Comment: @Glorfindel The difference is that a website that tells about the differences between two words that are often confused with each other would be fully automated, unlike SE.