# Suggestion to write app for girlfriend question is acceptable?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

I just saw a question below

> [I want to write an app for my GF, Any suggestions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790550/i-want-to-write-an-app-for-my-gf-any-suggestions)
>
> Ok here's the thing. She's my ex.
>
> I want to write an app for her (in Java) for V day. Nothing overly complicated, or overly love-ly. Something mild, something that says I miss her - but in a fun and interesting way.
>
> Suggestions?
>
> PS: I'm not sure what to tag this question. If this breaks any of the community's rules, I'm sorry.

which Is undeleted

> [image]

Does that mean this question is acceptable? Or if it's not acceptable, then isn't its undeletion and abuse of the 10k privilege?

Comment: Deleted again.[‍](http://www.google.com)

Comment: That was a horrible question and it definitely was not Stack Overflow material.

Comment: i just literally  rofl .. when saw that post ..

Comment: This also demonstrates a possible inconsistency in the system — 10k users need to wait 2 days to delete a question, but can undelete a question right away, as evidenced by Bojangles' vote.

Comment: @LoremIpsum i think they can not delete .. but vote to un-delete .. and its by design

Comment: [Who decides what questions don’t fit?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/)

Comment: If I ever try to write an app for V-day, I hope I start more than 5 days in advance.

Comment: @Shog9 _Users with 10,000+ reputation can delete questions that have been closed for 48 hours, if they cast three (3) votes for deletion. Questions can be undeleted through the same_ **process in reverse**. its undeleted in just after 6 hour after deleting

Comment: @AnnaLear OP forgot to mention that "It's URGENT you guys!"

Comment: The "process" here is 3 votes, @Null. The question's already closed - obviously you don't have to close it again to undelete.

Comment: @AnnaLear If I ever try to write an app for V-day, just shoot me and take me out of my misery, please.

Comment: @Yannis Hey, a deadline's a deadline. ;)

Comment: That whole question became a bit of a quick meme during the outage. For the entire duration of it, it was the top listed question on the front page of SO, which might explain its "popularity" if nothing more than a cult status.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question can't be answered reasonably, and quite frankly, I don't think we should be butting into his relationships in the name of software development.  That alone makes me feel awkward.

Even so, if I strip out the parts about his intentions, I'm left with...

> I want to write an app (in Java) for V day. Nothing overly
>   complicated. Something mild - but [done] in a fun and interesting way.
>
> Suggestions?

That's not even a good *question*.  It's asking for suggestions.

Comment: Of course it's a question, it ends with a question mark! ;P

Comment: @yannis  i want answer ? 

now is <<< question :P:P

Comment: @Yannis:  Har har.

Comment: @Yannis Of course it's a question, it ends with a question mark?  ;p

Answer (score 6):

Why is it not acceptable? Simple.

Stack Overflow is meant for specifically answerable questions, preferably with a definite answer. The question asks for a [**list of suggestions**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14308/should-poll-questions-be-community-wiki/14317#14317), and is therefore considered "not constructive".